# How to plot a chart with bars

Tags: graphics, diagrams, bar

I would like to know how I could plot a chart of this type in latex:
[image]

Maybe tikz would be helpful in this case? What would this kind of code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `TikZ` solution:

[image]

You can change the first `\forall` loop to `{1,2,3}` if you only want 3 levels. You can also change it to `{1,...,5}` or more, but the labels at the left will overlap and it starts to get pretty slow. You'll probably want to change the scale.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=10,yscale=5]
\draw (0,1)--(0,0)--(1,0)--(1,1);
\foreach \n[evaluate=\n as \M using 5^\n-1, evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n-1)] in {1,2,3,4}{
    \foreach \k in {1,3,...,\M}{
        \fill ({\k/(\M+1)},0) rectangle ({(\k+1)/(\M+1)},{1/3^(\m)});
        \node[left,font=\scriptsize\sffamily] at (0,{1/3^(\m)}){$1/3^\m$};
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```